# error while Deserialize the Google Direction json

Tags: android, google-maps, http, xamarin, direction

I have this json

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-22.8895625,-47.0714089&destination=-22.892376,-47.027553&key=

And I need deserialize it 
But I get this error

> Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 8, position 4.

What I am doing:

```
 public static async Task<List<Model.Localizacao>> GetDirectionsAsync(Localizacao locUser, Localizacao locLoja)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                List<Model.Localizacao> lstLoc = new List<Model.Localizacao>();
                var json = await client.GetStringAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + locUser.latitude + "," + locUser.longitude + "&destination="+ locLoja.latitude+","+locLoja.longitude+"&key=" + GOOGLEMAPSKEY);
                json = json.Substring(json.IndexOf('['));
                json = json.Substring(0, json.LastIndexOf(']') + 1);
                lstLoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Localizacao>>(json);
                return lstLoc;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my class:

```
namespace neoFly_Montana.Model
{
class Localizacao
{
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
}
}
```

How can I solve that?
My key is the same for the maps of google

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in these lines:

```
json = json.Substring(json.IndexOf('['));
json = json.Substring(0, json.LastIndexOf(']') + 1);
```

This appears to set `json` to be all the text from the first `[` to the last `]`. That means that you're going to wind up with some malformed json.

`geocoded_waypoints` is an array, but so is `routes`, which means you're going to wind up with a String that looks like this:

```
[
    { "geocoder_status" : "OK" ... }
    { "geocoder_status" : "OK" ... }
], "routes": [
    { "bounds": { ... } ... }
]
```

That `, "routes": [` will fail to parse.

### Update

After some discussion in the comments, I think I'm at the end of the help I'm able to provide. I'm not familiar with C# or the particular JSON parsing library you're using.

However, I can offer some ideas as a starting point.

The JSON coming back from that Google call has a particular structure. I suspect you will have to create new model classes that match this structure. For example, the top-level object would have three fields, and might look like this in Java:

```
public class ApiResponse {

    private List<Waypoint> geocoded_waypoints;
    private List<Route> routes;
    private String status;
}
```

Then you'd have to implement `Waypoint` and `Route`, again matching the structure of the Google response:

```
public class Waypoint {

    private String geocoder_status;
    private String place_id;
    private List<String> types;
}

public class Route {

    private Bounds bounds;
    private String copyrights;
    private List<Leg> legs;
    private Polyline overview_polyline;
    private String summary;
    private List<String> warnings;
    private List<String> waypoint_order;
}
```

And so on. Once you have a class to represent the top-level response as well as all the various sub-objects inside that response, you would probably be able to change this code:

```
            List<Model.Localizacao> lstLoc = new List<Model.Localizacao>();
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + locUser.latitude + "," + locUser.longitude + "&destination="+ locLoja.latitude+","+locLoja.longitude+"&key=" + GOOGLEMAPSKEY);
            json = json.Substring(json.IndexOf('['));
            json = json.Substring(0, json.LastIndexOf(']') + 1);
            lstLoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Localizacao>>(json);
            return lstLoc;
```

to this:

```
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + locUser.latitude + "," + locUser.longitude + "&destination="+ locLoja.latitude+","+locLoja.longitude+"&key=" + GOOGLEMAPSKEY);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(json);
```

Comment: Probably it is one problem...but if I comment this line, it doesn't deserelize because of the "["

Comment: Why bother stripping out everything before the first `[` and the last `]`? Why not just parse the whole string as json?

Comment: Because in other experiences, when did that, I got this error

Then, using that all used to happen good...but now I have a new case, the, I don't know 
"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[neoFly_Montana.Model.Localizacao]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array..."

Comment: I think I need to use json array somewhere to deserialize it, but, how I am a beginner, I've had problems with this part

Comment: I'm not familiar with `JsonConvert`, but this line `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Localizacao>>` should probably be changed to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeNewClass>` where `SomeNewClass` represents the whole google response. Maybe you could post the code you're using for `Model.Localizacao`?

Comment: I can. Wait a little

Comment: I am using List<myclass> cause I am converting to a list of my class...in other cases it is working perfectly, but when I have this new json that I posted here I have problems and errors with the deserealize

Comment: @JoycedeLanna I've updated my answer with some more information. I believe you'll have to take it from here.

Comment: your code seems work here, how can I get the routes class inside the class?
Thank you guy
very much